# How to break when DOM element gets removed from its parent?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I need a little help using the Chrome debugger.

I have a bug where a `canvas` element is getting inadvertently removed from its parent `div`.  I can't find the piece of code that's doing it.  I wanted to set a breakpoint when the `canvas` element gets removed or when the parent `div` element has an element removed from it.  I set all the "break on" features for both the parent `div` and the child `canvas` but none of them get fired.  Nevertheless, I observe that after executing the repro steps, the canvas is missing and that its `parentElement` becomes null.

Clarification: By "break on" features I mean: *subtree modifications*, *attribute modifications*, and *node removal* for both the parent `div` and the child `canvas`

```
<div>
    <canvas>
</div>
```

How can I set a breakpoint to find the offending code by catching it red-handed in the act of removing the `canvas`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [DOM Change Breakpoints](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/breakpoints#dom).

[image: DOM Change Breakpoint]

Setting a subtree modification breakpoint on the `div` should do the trick.