# jQuery object reference resolves to html content in fetch promise

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, fetch-api

I have written function below to load HTML to the jQuery element passed to it as jQuery object reference. It works fine inside the function itself. However, the object reference gets converted to HTML content of the reference. I need it as object reference only. Please help me as I can't find any resources or similar question to resolve this.

Here is the the function:

```
loadTargets(url, target) {

    console.log("target is ->" + target); // output: target is ->[object HTMLElement]

    $(target).html("loading..."); //  resolves properly and HTML is updated as intended to "loading..."

    fetch(url)
    .then((response) =>{
        return response.text();
    })
    .then((html) => { //passing target as additional arg doesn't help either
            jQuery(target).html(html); // doesn't work
            console.log("fresh target was: ", target) // Output: 'fresh target was: <header class="header"></header>'
    })
    .catch((err) => {});


}
```

Function call

```
config.loaders.forEach(function(loader, index) {
            $(loader.target).each(function(index, loaderTarget){  // <--- this is jquery selector specifying to loop over each occurence of ta
                loadTargets(loader.file, loaderTarget); // <-- here this refers to that specific occurence
            });
        });
```

I have verified that there is no problem with function call

Comment: Looks like the HTMLElement object stored in `target` variable gets detached from DOM while `fetch` is running. Could you confirm that by logging `target.parentNode` as well? If confirmed, you can either analyze your code statically, or find the reason for that detach by placing the corresponding breakpoint in your DevTools.

Comment: @raina77ow target.parentNode is undefined inside promise. while it returns  'body' element in the function. So yes, it is getting detached from DOM

Comment: The code shown doesn't do detach node (you can reconfirm it by placing logging after `$(...).html` op), so it means the problem is elsewhere. I'd suggest placing node removal breakpoint (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51816084/how-to-break-when-dom-element-gets-removed-from-its-parent)) and see what's happening behind the scenes. )

Comment: Even if I remove target from DOM, calling `console.log(target)` will log it as an object, not as HTML string as in your case. Also note you use `console.log(message + target)` first time and `console.log(message, target)` second time. Try to unify.